# trying to assign xml into specific datagrid datafields

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

Coming back to flex after not using it for a while, trying to load some xml (generated by php) into a datagrid using dataprovider to create a simple grid showing the daily high and low temperatures over the course of a week. I can get the data to display in my datagrid, but the columns are loading in random order. (so friday is coming before monday etc.) So I'm just trying to figure out how to assign specific data to specific datafields.

Here's the flex code; (updated to working code. Note that the dataFields simply contain the names of the xml tags and/or the names of the tags within those tags)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="weather"  url="http://localhost/weather/index.php" result="weather_resultHandler(event)" fault="weather_faultHandler(event)" />
</fx:Declarations>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        //Setup array making sure to import Array Collection
        [Bindable]
        public var mydata:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        protected function weather_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.result.weather.city);
            //mydata is our array and we are adding the info to it.  Show the xml file.
            mydata = event.result.weather.city;             
        }

        protected function weather_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            //import Alert so we can use this class
            Alert.show("There is a problem with the data connection");
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:DataGrid x="49" y="226" id="weatherGrid" dataProvider="{mydata}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="City" dataField="name"/> 
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="High" dataField="mon.high"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="Low" dataField="mon.low"/>                
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="High" dataField="tues.high"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="Low" dataField="tues.low"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="High" dataField="wed.high"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="Low" dataField="wed.low"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="High" dataField="thurs.high"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="Low" dataField="thurs.low"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="High" dataField="fri.high"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="Low" dataField="fri.low"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="High" dataField="sat.high"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="Low" dataField="sat.low"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="High" dataField="sun.high"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="40" headerText="Low" dataField="sun.low"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

And the xml the php generates is this; (edited based on comment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><weather><city>
    <name>London</name>
    <mon>
        <high>-2</high>
        <low>-10</low>
    </mon>
    <tues>
        <high>-1</high>

        <low>-5</low>
    </tues>
    <wed>
        <high>0</high>
        <low>-2</low>
    </wed>
    <thurs>

        <high>3</high>
        <low>0</low>
    </thurs>
    <fri>
        <high>5</high>
        <low>2</low>
    </fri>

    <sat>
        <high>8</high>
        <low>4</low>
    </sat>
    <sun>
        <high>10</high>
        <low>6</low>

    </sun>
</city><city>
    <name>Toronto</name>
    <mon>
        <high>-5</high>
        <low>-10</low>
    </mon>

    <tues>
        <high>-8</high>
        <low>-15</low>
    </tues>
    <wed>
        <high>-2</high>
        <low>-7</low>

    </wed>
    <thurs>
        <high>3</high>
        <low>-3</low>
    </thurs>
    <fri>
        <high>6</high>

        <low>0</low>
    </fri>
    <sat>
        <high>7</high>
        <low>3</low>
    </sat>
    <sun>

        <high>9</high>
        <low>4</low>
    </sun>
</city></weather>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice to you would be to iterate through you xml and transform it into a data model to make it easier to work with.  Something like

```
WeatherModel
   monday
      high
      low
   tuesday
      high
      low
   wednesday
      high
      low
   thursday
      high
      low
   friday
      high
      low
   saturday
      high
      low
   sunday
      high
      low
```

This way you can just add the actual day to the column datafield.  You don't need to use the straight xml, which is annoying to work with anywho.  Just need to map it to an object.  You can use [Spicefactory's XML object mapper](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.3/manual/xmlmapper.php#intro) to do the work.

Comment: I get the logic behind the data model, but wouldn't I have the same problem with the results filling into the grid out of order? I'd prefer not to use an external library if possible.

Comment: Not at all, like I said, you just need to specify the property of the dataField in the column to the name of the day.  The external library is just to help out, you can do it yourself if need be.

Comment: Wow, I was totally overthinking that one, I didn't think it'd be that easy. :P Thanks for your help!